# How to check specific Headers columns of an excel sheet using sheetjs in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sheetjs

My requirement is to read an excel sheet and check for specific header columns if they exist or not.
I'm using sheetjs to read the values of the header columns.

But, it is trying to collect all the header column names, but I want only certain cells at certain indexes.
How can I collect only certain specific headers ?

```
validateMissingHeaders = (sheet) => {
    var headers = [];
    var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet['!ref']);
    var C, R = range.s.r; /* start in the first row */
    /* walk every column in the range */
    for(C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {
        var cell = sheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:C, r:R})] /* find the cell in the first row */

        var hdr = ""; // <-- replace with your desired default 
        if(cell && cell.t) hdr = XLSX.utils.format_cell(cell);

        headers.push(hdr);
    }
    console.log(`-- Headers collected :`, headers);
}

fileChange = event => {
    const inputFile = event.target.files[0];
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(inputFile);
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        const bufferArray = e.target.result;
        const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });
        const wsname = wb.SheetNames[1];
        const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
        this.validateMissingHeaders(ws);
    };
}
```

Can someone please provide solution to this.

Comment: If you know the headers you are interested in are in columns e.g. `[1, 3, 5]`, then you can check the value of `C` is in that array ? Perhaps you can add an example of the headers and the ones you are interested in into the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
const HEADERS_MAP = new Map();
HEADERS_MAP.set(0, "Item");
HEADERS_MAP.set(1, "Name");
HEADERS_MAP.set(3, "Age");
HEADERS_MAP.set(5, "Address");

validateMissingHeaders = (sheet, errors) => {
        var missingHeaders = [];
        HEADERS_MAP.forEach((value, index) => {
            var cell = sheet[XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c:index, r:0})]
            var header = "";
            if (cell && cell.t) {
                header = XLSX.utils.format_cell(cell);
                if (value !== header) {
                    missingHeaders.push(value);
                }
            }
        });
        if (missingHeaders.length !== 0) {
            errors.push({
                row: "Missing Headers",
                column: missingHeaders,
            });
        }
    }

fileChange = event => {
    const inputFile = event.target.files[0];
    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(inputFile);
    fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        const bufferArray = e.target.result;
        const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });
        const wsname = wb.SheetNames[1];
        const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];
        this.validateMissingHeaders(ws);
    };
}
```